# swt.jar where is it?

Tags: java, swt

Anyone know where I can download swt.jar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get it under "releases" on the [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) eclipse page.

Answer (score 12):

If you have Eclipse IDE installed, you can find the jar file in eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.swt**.jar

Answer (score 3):

Now the real download page is:

https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.10-201812060815/#SWT

At the bottom, under "SWT Binary and Source" part. You see these files:

```
Windows (64 bit version)             swt-4.10-win32-win32-x86_64.zip
Linux (64 bit version)               swt-4.10-gtk-linux-x86_64.zip
Linux (64 bit version for Power PC)  swt-4.10-gtk-linux-ppc64le.zip
Mac OSX (64 bit version)             swt-4.10-cocoa-macosx-x86_64.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the [Java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgeclipseswt31jar.htm) and below the code you can find download button, not only this jar you can find many(official) jar files from there.

Also you can find tutorials(if interesting) for swt jar from [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipse.html).

*I know this answer after seven years but this may be helpful to someone who is looking for this plugin.*